# java.util.logging.Logger: increment of file-extension after a "timeout"

Tags: java, java.util.logging

I am using java.util.logging.Logger and wrapped it in a singleton. So I can access it in a nice way all over my programm (also in threads).

```
import java.util.logging.*;
import java.io.*;

public class LogTest 
{
   public static void init () throws Exception
   {
      LogManager.getLogManager().reset ();
   }

   public static Logger get () throws Exception
   {
     Logger l = LogManager.getLogManager ().getLogger ("test");
     if (l == null)
     {
        l = Logger.getLogger ("test");
        FileHandler fh = new FileHandler ("test.log", 100000, 1, true);
        l.addHandler (fh);
        l.setLevel (Level.parse ("INFO"));
     }
     return l;
   }
}
```

I think thats much better than a global or passing references.

I call LogTest.init () at the very beginning in my main.
Then afterwards I call LogTest.get () everywhere I need to to logging. Even if it is a thread.

```
LogTest.get().info ("blabla");
```

That is working well. But I recognized that after 1-2 minutes when I did not print some lines to the logfile the file-extension increments by 1.

test.log -> test.log.1
....
test.log.1 -> test.log.2

I would expect that ONLY if the filesize exceeds the maximum (100k of FileHandler)

Any idea if that is a problem related to threads or the FileHandler? Why is that behaviour? I would not expect that change of logfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason this happens lies probably here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/logging/LogManager.html#getLogger(java.lang.String)

> It is also important to note that the Logger associated with the String name may be garbage collected at any time if there is no strong reference to the Logger. The caller of this method must check the return value for null in order to properly handle the case where the Logger has been garbage collected.

Since you do not access the logger for one or several minute and there is no reference to the logger object in your code, it's probably garbage collected and when you later call `getLogger()` it probably returns null.

If you had a proper Singleton as pointer by @Mark, it would not be garbage collected.

Comment: In my real code the class is a real singleton. But the problem was that the instance of the logger was not member in my singleton. I always asked LogManager for the named logger. And with that sure GC would delete it. Thanks for the tip. Now  having the logger as a variable in the singleton it is working well.

Answer (score 1):

Unrelated to your question, your code is more of a class with static methods than it is a singleton.

From [When is a singleton not a singleton](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/singleton-1577166.html):

> The Singleton is a useful Design Pattern for allowing only one
>   instance of your class, but common mistakes can inadvertently allow
>   more than one instance to be created.

With your code you can still call `new LogTest()` as many times as you want, therefore allowing more than `one` instance to be created.

---

Your code as singleton would look something like this:

```
public class LogTest {

    private static LogTest theInstance;

    private LogTest() {
        LogManager.getLogManager().reset();
    }

    public static synchronized LogTest getInstance() {
        if(theInstance == null) {
            theInstance = new LogTest();
        }
        return theInstance;
    }

    public Logger getLogger() throws Exception {
        Logger l = LogManager.getLogManager().getLogger("test");
        if (l == null) {
            l = Logger.getLogger("test");
            FileHandler fh = new FileHandler("test.log", 100000, 1, true);
            l.addHandler(fh);
            l.setLevel(Level.parse("INFO"));
        }
        return l;
    }
}
```

When you want to use it:

```
LogTest.getInstance().getLogger().log(...);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I skipped the private constructor when I created a simple example for my question - and did miss the fact that it is no singleton then anymmore. The real - more complex singleton does have it. But for the question it does not make any difference.